# Webservices wcfstorm client

Tags: asp.net

I am using WCFstrom lite to find the problem with the webservice connection. It comes up with the error

"
The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element.RSS Feed
"

But as it is lite version I cannot find any configuration on the wcfstrom.

My web config looks like.

```
<system.serviceModel>
<extensions>
  <behaviorExtensions>
    <!-- Declare that we have an extension called WSDL Extras-->
    <add name="wsdlExtensions" type="WCFExtras.Wsdl.WsdlExtensionsConfig, WCFExtras, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
  </behaviorExtensions>
</extensions>
<services>
              <service name="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" behaviourConfiguration="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx">
                    <!-- Service Endpoints -->
                    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="WcfExtras.EndpointBehavior" contract="xxxxxxxxxxxx">
                          <!-- 
          Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed or replaced to reflect the 
          identity under which the deployed service runs.  If removed, WCF will infer an appropriate identity 
          automatically.
      -->
                          <identity>
                                <dns value="localhost" />
                          </identity>
                    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="WcfExtras.EndpointBehavior" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
        </services>
        <behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="WcfExtras.EndpointBehavior">
      <wsdlExtensions location="http://localhost:3893/xxxxxxxx.svc" singleFile="true" />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
                    <behavior name="xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx">
                          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
                          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
                          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
                    </behavior>
              </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
```

Where do I add the following code:

```
  <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="LoggedInUsersSoap" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
              <security mode="None" />
            </binding>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer, just select the service in the wcf Client and edit on end points then you can edit the maxReceivedmessages property

Answer (score 1):

In WCFStorm (at least in the current 1.3.0 version), you can also increase the MaxReceivedMessage by loading a client app.config file which has a the right (large) value.

http://www.wcfstorm.com/wcf/loading-client-appconfig-files.aspx